# multivariate hypergeometric distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, covariance

Is there a good textbook or a journal article which describes the properties of the multivariate hypergeometric distribution? I am particularly interested in the covariance structure. Wikipedia gives some basic results but without any citations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check

> Johnson, N. L., Kotz, S., & Balakrishnan, N. (1997). Discrete
>   multivariate distributions (Vol. 165). New York: Wiley.

There is also nice description in http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/MultiHypergeometric.html